# MongoDB Aggregation - How to match dates

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data like this:

```
[
  {
    date: "2021-12-01 00:00:00.0",
  },
  {
    date: "2021-12-02 00:00:00.0",
  }
]
```

I am trying to see if it matches a date that is stored in a string. My query is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      report_date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$date"
        }
      },
      report_date3: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "2021-12-01"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      report_date: "$report_date3"
    }
  }
])
```

But it is not returning any documents. How do I match this string with the date?

Comment: Why on earth do you store date values as string? Store proper `Date` objects.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am not storing dates as a string. I am searching for dates using a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross-field comparison, you need [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#restrictions) in the `$match` query.

> The `$match` query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax; i.e. `$match` does not accept raw aggregation expressions. To include aggregation expression in `$match`, use a `$expr` query expression:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      report_date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$date"
        }
      },
      report_date3: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "2021-12-01"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$report_date",
          "$report_date3"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l6WL4rKUTmQ)